# Is msal-browser fit/safe for use for Outlook Addins in acquiring GRAPH tokens?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, outlook-web-addins, msal.js, outlook-graph-api

I have an outlook addin that runs on REST-APIs. I want to migrate it to GRAPH and I am currently exploring the possibility of using the MSAL-browser library to get the GRAPH access tokens. I am currently using this as [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code). This was mentioned in this [stack-overflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700294/office-outlook-web-add-in-with-graph-api-connect-to-graph-api-without-pop-up)

I find the 'Single Page Application' solution straight forward, not requiring much interaction with the addin host server. I intend to use its authRedirect flow.

Although I have my own opinions/conclusions, I would like to ask some expert thoughts on the following :

1. [Does MSAL-browser library work for all platforms now?](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1072) (i.e. Windows Outlook client, IPhone/Android Outlook client, MAC-Outlook client and browser-OWA outlook)
2. Is it safe to use MSAL-browser for an outlook addin?
3. If it is not safe, what other alternative is there that does not require much interaction with the addin server?

Thank you very much for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

We are actively working on MSAL library and currently it is not supported in OWA. As an alternative you can use ADAL library

Comment: Any updates about msal library and compatiblity with mac outlook ?